# Does my app stop if I renew my provisioning profile on a new certificate (Enterprise Distribution Method)?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, sign

I have an application that was released by an enterprise distribution method. The distribute certificate will expire in one month so I created a new one. 

In addition, I renewed the provisioning profile based on a new certificate with the same bundle ID and app ID.

The old provisioning profile will expire in one month as like as the old certificate. My app was signed and installed by this provisioning profile and certificate.

> So the question is will my existing application that is being used by
>   our users right now stop working when I renewed the certificate and
>   provisioning profile?

Comment: No, It will not affect your live application. whenever if your certificated is expired that means you can not upload a new build to app store.

Comment: @Saurabhpandey Thanks Saurabh but it related to enterprise account not app store account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't revoke the old certificate you will be fine.

With the enterprise program you can have two valid signing certificates at any point; This allows you to issue a second one before the first expires.

Comment: I guess this is also valid answer on my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73912298/swapping-certificate-into-provisioning-profile-in-use .. And yeah the revoking the certificate is "the kill switch" in Enterprise distribution..